# Vaadin Accordion with Button in summary

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

In my Vaadin 14 app, I want to add an `Accordion` component that has several components in its summary (which is always displayed), among which a `Button`.  Clicking in the summary normally toggles the display of the `AccordionPanel` content.  How can I prevent the `AccordionPanel` to collapse/expand when the button in the summary is clicked?

Objects are created simply as follows:

```
Accordion accordion = new Accordion();

MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();

accordion.add(panel);
```

with `MyPanel` constructor simply calling `setSummary()` with a layout containing the button.

Comment: Can you add a code sample of how you're creating your components?

Comment: @ollitietavainen simply `new Button(...)` and then adding a click listener, nothing special.

Comment: No, I mean about the `Accordion`, `AccordionPanel` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer [in this thread on the forum](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/18535411/details-component-with-button-in-summary-need-to-prevent-content-from-ope).

It turns out you can prevent the propagation of the button click with this hack:

```
button.getElement().addEventListener("click", click -> {
        //do nothing
}).addEventData("event.stopPropagation()");
```

This seems like a core functionality that the framework should provide out of the box, but [this ticket](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/1363) is still open.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to your view:

```
    UI.getCurrent().getPage()
    .executeJs("Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('vaadin-accordion-panel')).forEach(element=>element.shadowRoot.querySelector(\"div[role=button]\").replaceWith(element.shadowRoot.querySelector(\"div[role=button]\").cloneNode(true)))");
```

will disable all clicks on all the accordions toggle and accordion summary. However you will need to include a button or trigger for opening and closing the accordion. I don't know if this is what you want?

Comment: No, I'd like the regular behaviour to keep working.  I just don't want the button click event to be handled by the button's click listener and not propagate to the accordion.

Comment: To clarify: you'd like the button to be completely read-only and not do anything different than clicking somewhere else within the summary?

Comment: @AnnaKoskinen No: I want the button to work as buttons normally do, but without triggering the accordion open/close toggle.  Clicking next to the button, should trigger the open/close toggle as usual.